# How do I delete every ocurrence of a word that is followed by another, without altering the whitespace?

Tags: shell, sed, find-and-replace, awk, text-editing

Suppose my file looks like this:

```
foo  bar
 foo    bar bar
foo foo      bar  foo
```

What I want to do is delete every `foo` that is followed by a `bar` (i.e. there is only whitespace between them), without changing any of the whitespace. Down below, I have replaced all the characters that should be deleted with underscores to make this clear:

```
___  bar
 ___    bar bar
foo ___      bar  foo
```

The command should result in the following file:

```
  bar
     bar bar
foo       bar  foo
```

How could I achieve this with sed or awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found out how to do this. The command to do this with sed would be:

```
sed -i -E 's/foo([[:blank:]]*)bar/\1bar/' file
```

Answer (score 3):

With anything which supports perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE), you can use a positive lookahead:

```
perl -pe 's/foo(?=\s*bar)//' < txt
```

`(?=)` is a "*zero-width positive lookahead assertion*".

It needs to match for the whole RE to match, but it doesn't include what it matches, so you don't need to capture and re-insert the matched text.

There are also negative lookahead, and positive and negative lookbehinds, all collectively called "lookarounds".

Comment: Should probably be `/foo(?=.+bar)/`, going by the description in the question, since your version will also change `foobar` (with zero spaces) to `bar`.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Probably depends on whether "only whitespace" means "1 or more whitespace characters" or "0 or more whitespace characters". OP's own answer uses `*`, so I'll err on the side of "0 or more", but indeed, if it should be "1 or more" it would be `+`.

Comment: Do you think `perl -pe 's/foo(?=\s*bar)//' ` might be better? With the `\s*` atom you avoid problems with matches later in the line, so that lines like `foo and some other words then bar` remain untouched.

Comment: @jubilatious1 ah indeed, I had missed the “if there’s only white space between them”. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -pe 's:g/   foo <?before \s* bar> //;'   file

#OR

~$ raku -pe 's:g/ <(foo)>        \s* bar //;'  file
```

The answers above are coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Advantages of Raku include high-level Unicode support built-in, as well as a robust/refined Regex implementation. Above, Raku Regexes are whitespace-tolerant in the recognition domain (left half of `s///`), so Regex atoms can be spread-out (and lined up).  Also, all Regex modifiers such as `:global` (or `:g`) move to the head of the `s///` operator in Raku. Like Perl, the global flag or "adverb" allows more than one match per line.

The first answer is a rough translation of @jcaron's excellent Perl(5) answer. Note in Raku, positive lookaheads are spelled `<?before ... >`. The second answer uses Raku's `<(`...`)>` capture markers, so that after all three atoms match, only `foo` is retained in the capture (and deleted in the replacement).

Both answers specifically change `foo` before `bar` with only whitespace in-between. This is an important point: given the phrase "my valentine, my bloody valentine" the Raku code `s:g/my <?before \s* valentine> //` will remove the first "my" (because "my-*is_before*-valentine"), but the second "my" remains untouched.

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org